# Create tag [oracle-fusion]? Deprecate [fusion]?

Tags: support, tag-creation

There are a multiplicity of "fusion" products, and they're all different.

Many have their own tags already (21 "fusion-" tags already exist), but Oracle's Fusion (a Middleware/Enterprise Bus technology) doesn't have one.

This was a bit of a problem when I tried looking for questions on Oracle Fusion.

Comment: Oh, fusion-middleware does exist w/1 question. In some ways thats better (no company name) but on other ways worse (Middleware is non-descriptive).

Comment: ... nuclear-fusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[fusion](/questions/tagged/fusion) has so many uses it is a bit of a meta-tag.

I've created [oracle-fusion-middleware](/questions/tagged/oracle-fusion-middleware) (and [oracle-fusion-apps](/questions/tagged/oracle-fusion-apps)), and retagged the obvious ones I could find (11 so far), and did some retags for [boost-fusion](/questions/tagged/boost-fusion),  [fusioncharts](/questions/tagged/fusioncharts), [google-fusion-tables](/questions/tagged/google-fusion-tables) and [vmware-fusion](/questions/tagged/vmware-fusion).

Some disambiguation work could still be done on the ~65 remaining [fusion](/questions/tagged/fusion) questions.

Comment: I'll work on retagging the questions. Thanks!